# Ajax GET request is empty despite correct query string parameter

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Using a simple Ajax GET request to retrieve some data, it successfully checks `if($request->ajax()) {}` but then fails any validation because there is no data in the `Request $request` variable. This happens only on the production server, on localhost everything works fine.

The console shows the intended URL `https://example.com/employeeInfo?id=1`, then error 422 (Unprocessable Entity). Output from `error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) { alert('Exception:', exception); }` gives an empty alert message.

**View**

```
<script>
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".team-pic").off("click").on("click", function() {
         $id = $(this).data('id');

         // Get data
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'employeeInfo',
            data: {'id':$id},
            success: function(data){
                var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
                // Show output...
            },

             error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                alert('Exception:', exception);
            }
        });

      });
});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/employeeInfo', 'EmployeeController@get');
```

**Controller**

```
public function get(Request $request) {

    if($request->ajax()) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'id' => 'required|integer',
        ]);

        // Id
        $employee = Employee::find(request('id'));

        // Create output
        $data = ...
        echo json_encode($data);

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, if you're going to use `alert`, it only takes **one** string argument. Eg `alert(status + ': ' + exception)`. Personally, I'd use `console.error(status, exception)`

Comment: I think what you are looking for in your `$employee = Employee...` line is: `$employee = Employee::find($request->input('id'));` Also I think in your `validate` line I think you want `$request->all()`

Comment: What `request()` function do you mean? `if($request->ajax())...`? I could leave it out, but the `$request` variable will still be empty.  And thanks for the `console.error` suggestion. It doesn't provide new information however.

Comment: @Phil turns out the `request` helper works as he is using it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-request Which also renders the first half of my above comment incorrect.

Comment: @ajon cheers! I don't know Laravel very well and wouldn't have imagined there'd just be global functions available in such a strict OOP framework. The more you learn, eh 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would use a RESTful API with [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding), specifically the explicit binding.

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot() 
{
    parent::boot();
    Route::model('employee', App\Employee::class);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('api/employees/{employee}', 'EmployeeController@get');
```

**Controller**

```
public function get(Employee $employee)
{
    // The id being valid is already done by forcing it to be an Employee
    // It is also an ajax call because it is going to the api route
    // This will json_encode the employee object.
    return $employee;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't use route model binding before, but reading into it, I got your solution to work with some modifications making it even simpler: left `RouteServiceProvider` for what it was, Route `Route::get('employee/{employee}', 'EmployeeController@get');`, and the controller as you suggested. I will credit your answer as correct. Thanks!